# Logical operators in grep in Ruby exec is erroring out

Tags: ruby

While executing the below mentioned shell command in Ruby I am seeing `org.jruby.exceptions.MainExitException: aborted` error message. Can someone help me in fixing this?

```
exec("cd /ABC/XYZ; grep -E \"/db/instance\" db_info.txt | grep \"username\"")
```

Comment: have you tried with backticks instead of exec? `\`cd /ABC/XYZ; grep -E /db/instance db_info.txt | grep username\``

Comment: also maybe try with single quotes inside your exec statement like so `exec("cd /ABC/XYZ; grep -E '/db/instance' db_info.txt | grep 'username'")`

Comment: Instead of `cd ...; grep ...` use `grep ... /ABC/XYZ/db_info.txt ...`. Are you _sure_ you want to use `exec`, which `"Replaces the current process by running the given external command..."`. In other words, your Ruby script disappears and the system call runs, resulting in jRuby thinking the script aborted. Try using `%x(...)`, or one of the `popen` variants.

Comment: Using Ruby as a fancy shell wrapper for stuff like this is really missing the point of Ruby. Why not `File.readlines('/ABC/XYZ/db_info.txt').grep(%r[/db/instance]).grep(/username/)`?